# Server programming and DataBase manipulation

Tags: ajax, database, asynchronous, server, request

I'm creating an app/startup with a friend, we are students of the first year of CS. We have never had experience with server programming, can someone give us some advice? Our server should work with external databases, not created by us, and possibly manipulate them. For example, if the user clicks a certain, I don't know… box, the server has to ask the database of that precise box and obtain the remaining objects contained in that box as an answer and show them to the user. If now the user decides to take one of the things contained the server must subtract 1 from the total and update the database in this way.
So first the server have to understand what database the user is searching for and then it has to manipulate that precise DB. It would be perfect if they were asynchronous requests.
Now, we need some advice ahahah. How the server should be structured, how powerful and safe it should be and above all how to program it, what language should be used? In general, how we must move(^*^')?
I apologize for any errors, I'm Italian(^*^').